# Fedena undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting this error while Installing Fedena 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Rails 2.3.5
Rake 0.8.7

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:268:in `=='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:412:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:411:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/tareen/ansi/config/environment.rb:5
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23
```

Comment: Clean up formatting of stack trace. OP should add more info to this post, namely what the fifth line of his environment.rb file is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

removed rubygems-update 2.4.2
and installed 1.6.2

and wow.